# Can I use the C++11 brace initialization syntax to avoid declaring trivial constructors for simple aggregates?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list, list-initialization

Let's say I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    int tag = 0;
    std::function<void ()> code;
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Foo> v;
}
```

And now I want to add a new `Foo` item to the vector with the specific `tag` and `code` **without** explicitly creating a temporary. That means I must add a constructor for `Foo`:

```
struct Foo
{
    inline Foo(int t, std::function<void ()> c): tag(t), code(c) {}

    int tag = 0;
    std::function<void ()> code;
};
```

And now I can use `emplace_back`:

```
v.emplace_back(0, [](){});
```

But when I had to do this again - for the 100th time - with a newly created struct, I thought: can't I use the brace initializer? Like so:

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
   int tag = 0;
   std::function<void ()> code;
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Foo> v;
   v.push_back(Foo{ 0, [](){} });
}
```

That gives me a compilation error (cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'Foo'), but I hope this can be done and I've just got the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++11, you can't use an *aggregate initializer* with your `struct` because you used an *equal initializer* for the non-static member `tag`. Remove the `= 0` part and it will work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
   int tag;
   std::function<void ()> code;
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Foo> v;
   v.push_back(Foo{ 0, [](){} });
}
```

Comment: Note this changes in C++14, where `Foo` is an aggregate and can be initialized using aggregate initialization.

Comment: Wow, that's totally unexpected. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

According to the C++11 standard, `Foo` is not an aggregate, the presence of the *brace-or-equal-initializer* prevents it from being one.

However, [this rule was changed for C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3605.html), so if you compile your code with `-std=c++14` (or whatever your compiler's equivalent setting is), `Foo` will be an aggregate, and your code will compile successfully.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa2dec4025e8d15)

For a C++11 compiler, you must either remove the initializer, which will make `Foo` an aggregate, or provide a two argument constructor.

Comment: Gotta wait for Visual Studio 2015 for C++14 support :)